# MySQL complex joins within a table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a MySQL session table with below entries

```
sessionid conversationid agentid Reason 
  s1          c1            a1    r1
  s2          c1            a1    r2
  s3          c2            a2    r1
  s4          c3            a3    r2
```

I want `sesionid` for the rows where `agentid` and `conversationid`s are the same and first occurence of reason is `r1`.

Expected output:

```
  sessionid conversationid agentid Reason 
  s1          c1            a1    r1
  s2          c1            a1    r2
```

Comment: In requirement you have mentioned " where agentid and conversationid's are same" but in expected output there are not same.

Comment: Sounds more like you want all the rows where `conversationid` and `agentid` are the same **and** there's more than one record **and** there exists at least one record with `Reason` "r1". Does that sound more accurate to you?

Comment: Do you want the rows in which the values of "conversationid" and "agentid" are same as the value of "conversationid" and "agentid" in the first row with "Reason = r1"? Example - if "conversationid=c1" and "agentid=a1" for first row with "Reason = r1", then do u want all rows where "conversationid=c1" and "agentid=a1"??

Comment: What did you try ? Incidentally, 4 rows is rarely enough to be considered representative of the problem

Comment: yes Phil, that was the requirement. I got the answer as below. Please let me know if it can be further optimized.

Comment: "select b.sessionid,b.conversationid,b.agentid,b.closeReason,b.assignTs from
 (select * from session where substr(assignTs,1,10)='2018-07-11') as b
inner join
(select conversationid,agentid, count(*) c ,sessionid, closeReason from session where substr(assignTs,1,10)='2018-07-11' and conversationid in (select conversationid from session where closeReason = 'PENDING_CUST_UPDATE' and substr(assignTs,1,10)='2018-07-11') group by conversationid,agentid having c>1 ) as a 
 on a.agentid=b.agentid and a.conversationid=b.conversationid and a.closeReason = 'PENDING_CUST_UPDATE'

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  b.sessionid,
  b.conversationid,
  b.agentid,
  b.closeReason,
  b.assignTs
from
  (select
     *
   from
     session
   where
     substr(assignTs,1,10) = '2018-07-11'
  ) as b
inner join
  (select
     conversationid,
     agentid,
     count(*) c,
     sessionid,
     closeReason
   from
     session
   where
     substr(assignTs,1,10) = '2018-07-11'
   and
     conversationid in
     (select
        conversationid
      from
        session
      where
        closeReason = 'PENDING_CUST_UPDATE'
      and
        substr(assignTs,1,10) = '2018-07-11')
      group by
        conversationid, agentid having c > 1
     ) as a 
   on
     a.agentid = b.agentid
   and
     a.conversationid =b.conversationid
   and
     a.closeReason = 'PENDING_CUST_UPDATE'
   order by
     b.agentid,
     b.conversationid
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you thing this query answeres the question?

Comment: Thats grt. What if i want to figure out the sessions for conversationids handled by a single agent i.e. no conversationid can be linked to more than one agentid ??